# saving and loading multiple shards made by gensim similarity model

Tags: python, model, gensim

My data has more than 1 million rows and while training gensim similarity model, it is making multiple .sav files (model.sav, model.sav.0, model.sav.1 and so on..). Problem is while loading, it is loading only one sub-part, instead of all the sub-parts, hence performing horribly in prediction. Parameters/options are not working as per gensim documentation.

As per the gensim documentation - https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/similarities/docsim.html
Saving as file handle and giving the following params should have worked - :

1. model.save(fname_or_handle, separately = None)
2. model.load(filepath, mmap = 'r')

Even tried to -

1. pickle the .sav files ( this pickles the 1st shard only i.e. model.sav)
2. compressing all sub-parts as .gz file ( this compresses one shard only , not all the sub-parts) and also gives some sort of pickle error.

```
tf_idf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)

sims = gensim.similarities.Similarity('./models/model.sav',tf_idf[corpus],
                                          num_features=len(dictionary))
sims.save('./models/model.sav')

sims1 = gensim.similarities.Similarity.load(./models/model.sav)
```

Expected results should give all matching documents from corpus, but this gives only from model.sav (the file mentioned while loading). It does NOT even execute the other shards. I checked result from each shard.

Question: How do I use all the sub-files of gensim model to predict similarity of my test document, WITHOUT looping through every sub-file individually and then presenting union of those results.

Comment: Hi, Riya did you get any solution to that my problem is also very similar to yours. I need to load multiple indices saved using gensim similarity model.

Comment: no Mohsin. i ran prediction with different shards. It predicts results of different length. The shards cannot be merged.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that 'model.sav' serves as a sort of directory to access all the actual similarity shards.

What's your output from len(sims1)? Running the above code on a corpus of 65,536 entries (creates exactly two shards), I can save and load a corpus and check that it has the 65,536 documents. I can also add documents and further save/load.

Comment: mine is creating 5 shards and prediction results are not good...we checked result with each shard, by default it picks only model.sav.0